# is it possible to only have users log in with google?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I want to make a app that logs in only using google, is it required to use devise? how would i go about it, documents only show example with devise.

Thank you

Comment: [Watch this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth). Apply your newly found knowledge with the gem [omniauth-google-oauth2 gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). If you want, you can also take a look at [a repository I made](https://github.com/GuilhermeSimoes/omniauth-popup) that shows how to build your own site with omniauth.

Answer (score 1):

Devise is not *required*, but assuming you want some reasonable level of security you're going to want to use Devise rather than hand-rolling an authentication framework using just Google OAuth2 and some custom table setup.

Devise + omniauth-google-oauth2 = simple, clean Google authentication.

In my opinion you're much better off using Devise to handle this stuff. The amount of work already done by others that you'll end up duplicating by hand-rolling a solution is absurd.

And if you decide later that you want to add Facebook, Twitter or simple username/password authentication, the work is already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Devise is not required. The easiest way to do this would be with the [omniauth-google-oauth2 gem.](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2)

Directions are available on the [project's github page.](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2)

Comment: hi, if i want to now save the user info to database how do i do it without devise i dont understand how to connect login with my app sorry my question is unclear

Comment: It's not required, but is possible. See [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#google-oauth2-example)

Comment: hm im sorry i dont understand your response, I do not want to use devise, but i would like to save user to database to make difference between admin and user

Comment: Examples on how to do that can be found inside [the project's examples](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/blob/master/examples/omni_auth.rb) and at [this NetTuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/) (note, it's old, so you may need to make some changes)